About the general form of the derivative equation

$a_0f(x)+a_1\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x)+a_2\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x)+\cdots+a_n\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)=c.$

I tried to generalize this…
\begin{align}
& n=1: \\
& a_0f(x)+a_1f’(x)=c. \\
& a_0f(x)e^{(a_0/a_1)x}+a_1f’(x)e^{(a_0/a_1)x}=ce^{(a_0/a_1)x}. \\
& \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(a_1f(x)e^{(a_0/a_1)x}\right) = \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{a_1c}{a_0}e^{(a_0/a_1)x}\right). \\
\Rightarrow \; & a_1f(x)e^{(a_0/a_1)x}=\dfrac{a_1c}{a_0}e^{(a_0/a_1)x}+C_1. \\
\therefore \; & \boxed{f(x)=\dfrac{c}{a_0}+\dfrac{C_1}{a_1}e^{-(a_0/a_1)x}.} \\
\ \\
& n=2: \\
& a_0f(x)+a_1f’(x)+a_2f’’(x)=c. \\
\ \\
& a_0t^2+a_1t+a_2=0 \cdots t=\alpha, t=\beta. \\
& a_0(t-\alpha)(t-\beta)=a_0t^2+a_1t+a_0, \alpha+\beta=-a_1/a_0, \alpha\beta=a_2/a_0. \\
\ \\
\Rightarrow \; & a_0(f(x)-\alpha f’(x))-a_0\beta(f’(x)-\alpha f’’(x))=c. \\
\Rightarrow \; & \text{By the case } n=1, \\
& f(x)-\alpha f’(x)=\dfrac{c}{a_0}-\dfrac{C_1}{a_0\beta}e^{-x/\beta}. \\
& f(x)e^{-x/\alpha}-\dfrac{\alpha}{x}f’(x)e^{-x/\alpha} = \dfrac{c}{a_0}e^{-x/\alpha}-\dfrac{C_1}{a_0\beta} e^{-(\alpha+\beta)x/(\alpha\beta)} \\
=\Rightarrow\;& \dfrac{d}{dx}\left( -\dfrac{\alpha}{x}f(x)e^{-x/\alpha} \right) = \dfrac{c}{a_0}e^{-x/\alpha}-\dfrac{C_1}{a_0\beta} e^{-a_1x/a_2} = \dfrac{d}{dx}\left( -\dfrac{c\alpha}{a_0}e^{-x/\alpha}+\dfrac{a_2C_1}{a_0a_1\beta}e^{-a_1x/a_2} \right) \\
\Rightarrow \; & -\dfrac{\alpha}{x}f(x)e^{-x/\alpha}=-\dfrac{c\alpha}{a_0}e^{-x/\alpha}+\dfrac{a_2C_1}{a_0a_1\beta}e^{-a_1x/a_2}+C_2’. \\
\therefore\;& f(x)=\dfrac{cx}{a_0}-\dfrac{a_2C_1x}{a_0a_1\alpha\beta}e^{-x/\beta}-\dfrac{C_2’x}{\alpha}e^{-x/\alpha} \\
=\;& \dfrac{cx}{a_0}-\dfrac{C_1x}{a_1}e^{-x/\beta}-\dfrac{C_2’x}{\alpha}e^{-x/\alpha}. \\
&C_2’=\dfrac{\alpha}{a_1}C_2. \\
\Rightarrow\;& \boxed{f(x)=\dfrac{cx}{a_0}-\dfrac{x}{a_1}\left( C_1e^{-x/\beta}+C_2e^{-x/\alpha} \right)}
\end{align}
I couldn’t find any pattern of each form, and now my question is:
Is it possible to get the general form of this? If it is, what is it?

I mean... other than relating it to the zeros of the associated characteristic polynomial? Not sure.

I think a much more parsimonious solution is possible. Once had a professor say we were in a math class because we were lazy. He was dead on in my case.

The solution of that type of equation is very well known. Search linear differential equations with constant coefficients.
